# How to list all projects on computer (C, Java, Python, C++, etc...)

Tags: c, file, dirent.h

I want to write a program to list all projects I've got on my hard drive, whatever languages. So for example if I have something like `user/projects/C/decompressor/src/...` I want the program to ouput `decompressor`, which is the project root, as it contains `src` folders and so on. But there are too many case where the parent folder of `src` is not the real root folder:
`projects/C/my-app/release1/src/...` or `projects/C/another-project-in-c/master/src/...`

So before coding I wanted to know what would be the best way to do so ? I have a piece of code that doesn't works as I want:

```
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
      return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
          char path[1024];
          if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
              continue;
          snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
          //printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
          listdir(path, indent + 2);
      } else {
        if (strcmp(get_file_extension(entry->d_name), ".c") == 0) {
          char buffer[1024];
          realpath(name, buffer);

          printf("possible root folder = \"%s\" \n", get_parent(buffer)); 
        }
      }
    }
    closedir(dir);
```

and:

```
char* get_parent(char* filename) {
    return (dirname(filename));
}

const char* get_file_extension(const char* filename) {
    assert(filename != NULL);

    char buffer[1024];
    char* tmp = strcpy(buffer, filename);
    char *ext = strrchr(tmp, '.');

    if (ext == NULL)
        return (char*) tmp + strlen(tmp);

    for (char *iter = ext + 1; *iter != '\0'; iter++) {
        if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*iter))
            return (char*) tmp + strlen(tmp);
    }

    return ext;
}
```

I didn't mention it, but there's also the java project structure (`projects/JAVA/MyApp/com/lorem/ipsum/concrete-package`) to take in count.

Is this even possible with all the particular cases?

Answer (score 0):

Let `projects` be the overall projects' root, then you first want to scan all directories inside `projects` by using a `readdir` loop (given that each directory inside `projects` stands for a certain language and contains actual project directories).
While iterating, you want to scan each language folder itself for all `d_name`s that are contained.

To clarify what I'm talking about, I got some pseudo code for you:

```
dirp = opendir("/user/projects");
while (entp = readdir(dirp)) {
    inner_dirp = opendir(entp->d_name);
    while (inner_entp = readdir(inner_dirp)) {
        print(inner_entp->d_name)
    }
}
```

Note that if your folder structure is prone to change, you might want to go by a recursive approach.